# DataTable From Session Memory has No Columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-variables

Im trying to retrieve a datatable that I put into a session variable, however when i do it apears that there are no columns...

I have done this before in VB.NET, I'n now using C#, and it worked perfectly, and as far as i can see there is no change in the code other than the obvious syntax changes.

EDIT:

The dt (in part 2) variable has the right data when i look in the data visulization window, but i have noticed that the other properties associated with a datatable are abscent. When i hover over a normal looking datatable with my mouse it looks like the following: " dt ----- {System.Data.DataTable}" but in the class im working on it just looks like "dt ----- {}".  Also, after I return the session variable into the dt I clone it (dtclone = dt.clone(); ) and the clone is empty in the data visulizer.... what on earth!

EDIT 2:

I have now also tried converting the first datatable to a dataset, putting this in the session variable, and recoverting it back to a datatable in the class.

Am starting to wonder if it is a probelm with:

```
    dt.Load(sqlReader);
```

The data does appear after this step though in the dataset visualiser, but not after being cloned.

Code below.

All help very welcome!

Thanks in advance

Chris

1) SQL command in a webhandler, the results of which populate the datatable to be put into the session variable.

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    SqlDataReader sqlReader= default(SqlDataReader);        
    SqlDataAdapter sqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

    sqlReader = storedProc.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

    dt.Load(sqlReader);
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["ResultsTable"] = dt;
```

2) Part of the code in a class which performs calculations on the table:

```
    DataTable dt = (DataTable)HttpContext.Current.Session["ResultsTable"];
```

Comment: Have you checked that the `dt` variable has the right data, before you put it in the session variable?

Comment: This is probably because your `HttpContext.Current.Session["ResultsTable"]` can not be casted to a `DataTable`, is the 2) `dt` in your code equals to NULL?

Comment: @VoodooChild: I think a casting problem would cause an `InvalidCastException`, so he'd better look at his dt variable as you suggested.

Comment: I suggest you _edit_ your question if you need to add information to it. Comments are not a good place for added information.

Comment: `dt ----- {}` means it didn't get the data out. What's in the Session variable when you goto read it?

Comment: A datatable is put into the session variable, and then should be taken out and put into another, different datatable which has the "dt ----- {}" problem. Cant quite understand how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you call DataTable dispose after setting Session Var?
Because if you do this, solution is like this:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["ResultsTable"] = dt.Copy();
```

Comment: No i havent called Dispose.  I have however tried your solution and the same problems remains.  Thanks though!

Comment: Have you checked your Web.Config configuration about Cookies? Read more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: I ended up using the system cache instead.